# Restrict query to work only on a list of ids

Tags: sql, arrays, matlab, postgresql

I am working in Matlab. I have a function, which presently queries a single table.

Now I need to restrict the query to only work on a subset of the whole table. I want the query to only consider the ids that are saved in a cell array 'idlist'.

```
idlist = 1, 5, 10, 12, 20
```

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT musickey FROM musiccollection WHERE path = 'Users/Jur/abcdef.mp3'
```

I want the above query to only consider the records whose id is found in `idlist`. Keep in mind that `idlist` can be of any size. Also, since I am working in Matlab I have to generate a new query string using the `idlist` at that instance. So adding an `AND` in the `WHERE` cannot work for me.

I need something like this:

```
SELECT musickey FROM musiccollection
WHERE path = 'Users/Jur/abcdef.mp3'CONSIDER id = [idlist]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways. Simple and fast for ***long*** lists:

```
SELECT musickey
FROM   musiccollection
JOIN  unnest ('{1,5,10,12,20}'::int[]) id USING (id)
WHERE  path = 'Users/Jur/abcdef.mp3';
```

Providing `idlist` as `array of integer`.

Or, if it's more convenient to provide a `text` value with a comma-separated list inside:

```
SELECT musickey
FROM   musiccollection
JOIN   unnest(string_to_array('1,5,10,12,20', ',')::int[]) id USING (id)
WHERE  path = 'Users/Jur/abcdef.mp3';
```

Or for a ***short*** array:

```
SELECT musickey
FROM   musiccollection
WHERE  path = 'Users/Jur/abcdef.mp3'
AND    id = ANY ('{1,5,10,12,20}'::int[]);
```

Or a short list:

```
... 
AND    id IN (1,5,10,12,20);
```

Comment: my idlist is a cell array. my id field in the table is of type character varying. im creating the query using sprintf in matlab. How can I input the cell array in the query_string to obtain the second query you posted?? (i think that's what i need)

Comment: im attempting this, but it is not working:

SELECT id FROM musiccollection JOIN unnest(string_to_array(''7','4','9'', ',')) id USING (id) WHERE .....

remember the id's are character varying. I tried to use the def'n here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html

Comment: I don't know matlab, but I am pretty sure, unbalanced quotes are illegal anywhere. Also, in SQL, only single quotes are for values, double-quotes are for identifiers. Try `string_to_array('7,4,9', ',')` - like I posted.